# Text is not centering in React JS (and Tailwind CSS)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Recently, I've started playing with Tailwind CSS with React JS.

(I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2KHCWJ3gjs) by Adrian Twarog to install Tailwind on my React project.)

And I was trying to center a `h1` on my page, except...

[image]

...that's what happened. But to me, it doesn't make sense! I've already centered my text and everything.

**`App.js`**

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container place-items-center">
      <h1 className="text-7xl text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-wide text-center">
        Text
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**`tailwind.config.js`**:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        orange: "#f97b4f",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**`index.css`**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;900&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

My question is, how do I center my text in Tailwind CSS? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the container class cause it gives several widths based on the width of the screen.

```
 <div className="place-items-center">
  <h1 className="text-7xl text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-wide text-center">
    Text
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nuha! It works! And welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to center h1 tag inside div so you can try this

```
<div className="container flex justify-center">
   <h1 className="text-7xl text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-wide">
        Text
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Atif! I tried that just now, but it still isn't centered.

Comment: Than you should try
`<h1 className="text-7xl text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-wide text-center w-full">Text</h1>`

Comment: Please see if any tailwind class is applying or not?

Comment: I've tried testing if Tailwind CSS was applying to the site, and it did. Also, thank you for your help!

Comment: by the way it should work https://play.tailwindcss.com/H48WpDauOg. Whatever thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want use container class you want add center true in config file

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
     container:{
       center:true
     }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```js
 <div className="container place-items-center">
      <h1 className="text-7xl text-gray-800 uppercase tracking-wide text-center">
        Text
      </h1>
    </div>
```